# How do I use the result of one function in another?

Tags: javascript

sorry this is all of it now...taking me a while to get used to this site. I had no idea you guys would be so fast. Like I was saying the first functions runs fine, so I don't understand why I can't use this.DonutsPH in the getDonutsPD function.

```
  function donutStore(location, minCustPh, maxCustPh, averageDpC, hoursOpen) {
      this.location   = location;
      this.minCustPh  = minCustPh;
      this.maxCustPh  = maxCustPh;
      this.averageDpC = averageDpC;
      this.hoursOpen  = hoursOpen;
      this.donutsPerHourValue = 0;
      this.getDonutsPH = function() {
       console.log(this.donutsPerHourValue = (this.location + " needs " + (Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.maxCustPh - this.minCustPh) + this.minCustPh)) * this.averageDpC) + " donuts per hour.");
    };
    this.getDonutsPD = function() {
     console.log(this.getDonutsPH * this.hoursOpen);
    };
     var Downtown    = new donutStore("Downtown",       8, 43, 4.5,  24);
    var CapitolHill = new donutStore("CapitolHill",    4, 37, 2,    12);
    var SLU         = new donutStore("SouthLakeUnion", 9, 23, 6.33, 24);
    var wWood       = new donutStore("WestWood",       2, 28, 1.25, 12);
    var Ballard     = new donutStore("Ballard",        8, 58, 3.75, 16);
    var dNutStores = [Downtown, CapitolHill, SLU, wWood, Ballard];

    for(i=0; i < dNutStores.length; i ++) 
    {
      dNutStores[i].getDonutsPH();
      dNutStores[i].getDonutsPD();
    }
```

Comment: Btw sorry, still trying to figure out formatting for stackoverflow

Comment: You have some others properties in this object. What value it has?
Can you paste the entire object here?

Comment: Your first function returns `undefined`, which isn't a number; and you're not calling the function (so nothing *could* be returned, even if the function did return something).

Comment: your function isn't returning anything, it's only writing a message to the console.

Comment: @claies: while the function doesn't have an explicit `return` statement, *all* JavaScript functions return *something*, it's just that if nothing is assigned it returns `undefined`.

Comment: true, I may not have worded it quite right, but I was trying to make a point from a beginner's point of view.  no `return` statement should stick out as "not returning anything"

Comment: There are a lot of other problems here anyway, like the fact that if you just returned that string statement, and then tried to multiply that by a number......

Comment: Are we just going to ignore the fact that he is trying to calculate donuts per hour?

Answer (score 3):

`this.getDonutsPH` is a variable. In javascript functions can also be variables.

In order to run any function you need to append `()` to the function name, e.g.

```
this.getDonutsPH()
```

Second thing, doing a `console.log('blah')` does not return any value, you need to tell the function to return a value

```
this.getDonutsPH = function() {
    return this.location + " needs " + (Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.maxCustPh - this.minCustPh) + this.minCustPh)) * this.averageDpC) + " donuts per hour.";
}
```

Update: JoshBeam comment:-

I want to point out, too, that this.getDonutsPH * this.hoursOpen will return NaN, because this.getDonutsPH will return a string. Multiplying a string by a number will always return NaN.

Comment: I want to point out, too, that `this.getDonutsPH * this.hoursOpen` will return `NaN`, because `this.getDonutsPH` will return a string. Multiplying a string by a number will always return `NaN`.

Comment: @JoshBeam unless the string contains a valid number :P which I know it isn't in this case, but I'm trying to address his question only which was essentially "how do I get a function to return something"

Comment: Okay you got me there lol. But that's just if the number is the only thing in the string; then JavaScript will coerce the string to a number and then multiply it or do whatever math operation.

Comment: Yeah, I totally understand what you're getting at. I just pointed that out, because his question also asked "It always returns `NaN.`" So he may have two problems: the function not returning anything, and then the second problem he will encounter will still be that it will return `NaN`, which I assume isn't his intended output.

Comment: actually the `NaN` error isn't caused by the multiplication itself, but when javascript tries to convert the string into a number before the multiplication.